# Is sum of currents equal to capacitor current for NMOS Inverter with Capacitor as Load?

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, nmos

I found this in my lecture notes and could not understand how drain current is equal to sum of load and (IL) capacitor currents (ICL) given in the figure for a NMOS Inverter with capacitor load. By looking at the direction of currents, I would assume load current would be equal to sum of drain and capacitor load currents.

I would appreciate if there is anyone who can make it clear for me.

[image: NMOS Inverter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mesh current at the node between the load, the source of the fet and the terminal of C_L

\$I_L = I_D + I_{CL} \$

rearranging gets this equation:

\$I_{CL} = I_L - I_D   \$

So it doesn't make sense that they didn't follow their own nomenclature with the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The way the arrows are drawn, the formula should be

$$I_{CL} = I_L - I_D$$

There is a mistake on someone's part.